# How to store and retrive Arrays in NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

Hello friends I want to store NSMutableAray's in NSMutableAray and want to retrieve it.I'm able to store it but could not access it. my code is below:

```
NSMutableArray *muteArray;
NSMutableArray *muteArray_Master;
NSMutableArray *mutArrar_Level1;            


NSArray *Children = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Children"];

if (Children.count > 0) {
    muteArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:Children];
}

muteArray_Master= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
mutArrar_Level1= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];



[muteArray_Master addObject:muteArray]; // muteArray_Master array added one object successfully 

i = [muteArray_Master count]; // Here I have i=1

mutArrar_Level1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[muteArray_Master objectAtIndex:i-1]]; // But here mutArrar_Level1 not producing correct data.still it is with 0 objects
```

So my requirement is to store more than one NSMutableArray's in `NSMutableArray` and access all  in another.

Thanks
Deepak R

Answer (score 4):

First off, I'm afraid to tell you that you need to work on your variable names. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000146-SW1

Anyhow, here's how you add multiple arrays to an array:

```
NSMutableArray *parentArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    NSArray *childArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"a-%i", i], 
        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"b-%i", i], 
        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"c-%i", i],
        nil];

    [parentArray addObject:childArray];
}
```

And this is how you'd access all of them again:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    NSArray *childArray = [parentArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"Child Array %i", i);

    for (NSString *item in childArray) {
        NSLog(@"  Item: %@", item);
    }
}
```

Really easy :)

Comment: Thanks buddy and sorry about my variable naming.

Comment: No problem. You'll just do yourself and others on your team a favor if you adhere to the naming conventions. Also, please don't forget to upvote and accept answers.